# swapping views with cool page turn animation

Tags: objective-c, uikit, uiviewcontroller, core-animation, uibutton

Below is code that I'm using to swap views

```
MySecondViewController *tempVC = [[MySecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MySecondView"];
[self presentModalViewController:tempVC animated:YES];
[tempVC passDataWithString:@"a string" andColor:yellowcolor];
```

How can I get the cool page turning animation (as with iBook or ROAD RAGE SIGN)
I don't want the user to actually tap and drag his finger on the screen. I want him to push a button and the animation occurs by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at `UIViewAnimationTransition` values?  Use them in a UIView animation block. eg:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp 
forView:self.view cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: thats great but how do you slow the animation down. things move so quickly onmy screen that i cant tell.